# Need help for complicated sql update

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have a table which has many records. i am storing html data in a particular fields called **Data** of that table. html data in each records have many IMG tag like `<img src='test.gif' />`. as a sample page url here http://www.bba-reman.com/content.aspx?content=bba_reman_diagnostics_tools

go there and see that a page is showing many product images and all data comes from table. i want to use lazyload jquery plugin and for that IMG tag should look like `<img src="img/grey.gif" data-original="img/example.jpg" >`. so i need to update my table html data.

so i need to write a sql update statement which would iterate in all html data in all rows and find img tag inside the particular div find by ID and change src url of IMG tag like src will be fixed like `src="img/grey.gif"` for all images and add one attribute to all img tag like `data-original="img/example.jpg"`

i know my situation is bit horrible for update statement. please suggest a good way to update all IMG tag writing sql. thanks

Comment: Have you considered writing a script in your language of preference, which will connect to db and iterate over all records reading and updating them with the new data which you will generate in script? Nowadays you can do it even with javascript by means of Node.js

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that all your tags do actually end in `/>`, then this would work

```
UPDATE myTable
SET tag = LEFT(tag, CHARINDEX('/', tag) - 1) + 'data-original=''example.gif'' />'
```

However, that wouldn't change the quotes, as you have done in your question, and it wouldn't remove the closing slash before the tag end, as you have done in your question.

Comment: what will be stored in tag keyword?

Comment: I put in 'tag' as the column name because I wasn't 100% sure what your table looked like.